# Windows batch file commands and variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos, windows-console

I'm not sure whether it is possible, but what I need is a plain bat/cmd file that runs on windows 7 and does such things:

Step 1. `findstr` - it should find a specific string using regular expressions engine. Suppose we're looking for a number enclosed in tags `<id>123</id>` (suppose such a file is unique, so one value is returned). The command would print `123` to the screen, but I need to save it in a variable (don't know how).

Step 2. Another call to `findstr` on another directory. Now we want to find a file NAME (`/m` option) containing the value that we saved on Step 1 (in another group of files i.e. another directory). And again, save the result (name of the file) in a variable. Say, `file_123.txt` matches the criteria.

Step 3. Copy the file that we got as a result of the second `findstr` call (`file_123.txt`) to another location.

**The whole question turns around the point about how to save the result of windows commands to variables to be able to provide these values to subsequent commands as parameters.**

Answer (score 3):

The general way of getting command output in variables is

```
for /f %%x in ('some command') do set Var=%%x
```

(with various variations, depending on context and what exactly is desired).

As for your steps, I elaborate after lunch. There are some intricacies.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=1-20 delims=<>" %%A in (`FINDSTR "123" "path of file to search in"`) DO (
 SET var=%%B
)

ECHO %var%
```

Understand that delims will change depending on what 'separates' the parts of the output (whether its a space, a special character, etc.)

Step 2 & 3:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`DIR "Path" /A ^| FIND /I "%var%"`) DO (
 COPY /Y "%%A" "C:\New\Path\%%~nxA"
)
```